# const string won't allow variable as username

Tags: string, excel, expression, constants, vba

I get a constant expression error message when i use this:

```
 Const FName As String = "c:\users\" & AGuser & _
                         "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\graphs.jpg"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: A constant simply cannot include a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, and as the compiler will tell you, a Constant expression cannot contain variable information, function calls, or anything that can't evaluate at compile time.  So, this will not work:

```
Const FName As String = "c:\users\" & AGuser & "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\graphs.jpg"
Public AGuser as String
Sub foo()
    Aguser = Environ("username")
End Sub
```

And neither will this:

```
Const FName As String = "c:\users\" & Environ("username") & "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\graphs.jpg"
```

Etc.

The way I typically handle this is using a constant expression and a local/procedure level variable with the `Replace` function.

```
Const FName As String = "c:\users\%username%\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\graphs.jpg"

Sub foo()
Dim path As String
Dim AGUser as String
AGUser = Environ("username") 'Modify if you need to do something else...
path = Replace(FName, "%username%", AGUser)

MsgBox path

End Sub
```

Alternatively, simply create a `Function` called `FName` which returns the string:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function FName() As String
    FName = "c:\users\" & Environ("Username") & "\documents\Appraiser_Genie\working\graphs.jpg"
End Function

Sub test()
    MsgBox FName
End Sub
```